# how do I kill a specific IP address in MQ consumers or producers, which was using by a random guy for local setup in java

Tags: java, tomcat, messaging, mq

So, while testing a flow in QA environment, a random guy is using bad queue for his/her local setup to test their local changes, If there is an error in QA, as message moves to bad queue, as a random guy is reading the queue all the messages are redirect to his/her local and the QA testing is turning critical, finding that guy and making him to turn off the server is impossible.

Before even writing the service. First, I tried to kill my local tomcat by researching i found following commands in cmd and it worked.

netstat -aon |find /i "listening" |find "8080"

taskkill /F /PID 123

so I want to write a POST service, where I can kill the tomcat server for that user using JSON payload with custom message and ip address.
"You, have been using the QA readers, it is impacting the production delivery data hence we are kill your tomcat server TA DA !"
any leads will be appreciated!

Comment: You have local access to tomcat process and need to POST a request? Kill tomcat server for that user? Very confusing. Please provide problem example.

Comment: IBM MQ? If you know the IP connecting to the queue manager you can block them by IP from connecting then kill the running channel.  What version of mq is the queue manager running?